# jquery ajax passing more than one parameter

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to pass two request parameters by ajax using jquery. The following is what I do:

```
function querySummary(){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"internalSummary.action",
    data:{starttime:$("#starttime").val(),endtime:${"#endtime"}.val()},
    success: function(data) {
        $("#hello").html( data );
    }
});
```

}

I am trying to pass starttime and endtime two parameters, but get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Can anyone give some suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks alot!

Comment: When the error is "Unexpected token" it's generally just a typo you did, and they are usually not that hard to spot as the console will tell you pretty much where it is.

Answer (score 2):

You're using curly braces instead of parentheses on the second jquery select.  `data` should be as follows:

```
{starttime:$("#starttime").val(),endtime:$("#endtime").val()}
```

The names of the values can be quoted or unquoted; javascript assumes they are names and not variables.

Comment: sorry the '*', I was trying to make the font big. I don't have that. Now I changed it again. Thank yoiu